# Kotlin withTimeout does not work in Intellij gradle project

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

Run following code give me the wrong results:

code

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun timeElapsed(nano: Long, msg: String){
    println("$msg milliseconds: ${(System.nanoTime()-nano)/1000000}")
}
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    withTimeout(700) { 
        println("in timout")
        timeElapsed(start, "timeout before delay")
        delay(900)
        println("not show?")
    }
}
```

wrong result

```
in timout
timeout before delay milliseconds: 16
not show?
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 700 ms
```

run on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ give me the expected result:

```
in timout
timeout before delay milliseconds: 27
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCancellationException: Timed out waiting for 700 ms
```

My gradle setup

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.6.21'
}

group 'intro-coroutines'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.2")

    def coroutines_version = '1.6.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-debug:$coroutines_version"
```

Intellij version:
Build #IU-221.5080.210, built on April 11, 2022

kotline plugin version:
221-1.7.0-Beta-release-135-IJ5080.210

Java SDK: JavaSE-1.8

what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Can you call `timeElapsed` after the `delay` function returns and write the result?

Comment: Thanks @TomerArazy See my answer below, was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

finally, I figured out why, totally my fault:

I define a delay() function in another Kotlin file in the same package as follows:

```
suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long): Unit =
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        executor.schedule({
            cont.resume(Unit)
        }, timeMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
```

As this continuation is a non-cancellable one, so delay is not cancellable!
Sorry, lesson learned: function should be private, and check the import!